# Calendar getTimeInMillis() returns same value after changing hours and minutes

Tags: java, android

The problem occurs in the following scenario:

```
public void setCal(final Calendar calendar) {
  Calendar c1 = pickedDate;
  Calendar c2 = pickedDate;

  Log.d(TAG, c1.getTimeInMillis());
  Log.d(TAG, c2.getTimeInMillis());

  c1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
  c1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 20);

  c2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18);
  c2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);

  Log.d(TAG, c1.getTimeInMillis());
  Log.d(TAG, c2.getTimeInMillis());
}
```

After I compare values with `getTimeInMillis()` before and after calling `set()` method to both calendars, I notice they are the same. Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: what is the calendar parameter for?

Comment: The two values are the same of c2 (hour 18 minutes 30) ?

Comment: Won't both of them actually set `pickedDate` ? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because here:

```
Calendar c1 = pickedDate;
Calendar c2 = pickedDate;
```

You set both objects to `pickedDate`. So any change in any object will change the values in `pickedDate`, which is actually, both the instances `c1` and `c2`. One way to tackle this is changing those lines to:

```
Calendar c1 = (Calendar)pickedDate.clone();
Calendar c2 = (Calendar)pickedDate.clone();
```

This will set them to clones of `pickedDate`, ie, they will not be the same.